# Can't figure out why this sql query is not working

Tags: mysql, default-value

SQL Query:

```
CREATE TABLE mytbl.customer(
CustID int( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
FirstName varchar( 40 ) ,
LastName varchar( 40 ) ,
Street varchar( 50 ) ,
City varchar( 40 ) ,
State varchar( 40 ) ,
ZipCode varchar( 5 ) ,
Telephone varchar( 20 ) ,
CellPhone varchar( 20 ) ,
CellCarrier varchar( 20 ) ,
UserName varchar( 20 ) ,
PASSWORD varchar( 10 ) ,
SecretQuestion varchar( 80 ) ,
SecretAnswer varchar( 50 ) ,
UtilityCompanyID int( 10 ) ,
SwUpgrade int( 10 ) DEFAULT 1,
DateToSignIn timestamp DEFAULT 0000 -00 -0000 :00 :00 NOT NULL ,
LastLoginTime timestamp DEFAULT 0000 -00 -0000 :00 :00 NOT NULL ,
STATUS varchar( 20 ) DEFAULT 'Inacitve',
Email1 varchar( 60 ) ,
Email2 varchar( 60 ) ,
PoolID int( 10 ) ,
DeviceID int( 10 ) ,
Last_Modified_Timestamp timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( CustID )
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```

Phpmyadmin error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-00-00 00:00:00 NOT NULL,
    LastLoginTime timestamp DEFAULT 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ' at line 18
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Without checking the timestamp creation fields look wrong - you sure these work? DateToSignIn timestamp DEFAULT 0000 -00 -0000 :00 :00 NOT NULL ,
LastLoginTime timestamp DEFAULT 0000 -00 -0000 :00 :00 NOT NULL ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldnt you be putting those timestamp default values in "", i.e. "0000-00-00 00:00:00"?

Answer (score 1):

Your default timestamp value should be like this.

```
DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you got the default construct, but try:

```
LastLoginTime timestamp DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

from [`manual`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html)

> If a DEFAULT value is specified for the first TIMESTAMP column in a
>   table, it is not ignored. The default can be CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or a
>   constant date and time value.

and

> To specify automatic default or updating for a TIMESTAMP column other
>   than the first one, you must suppress the automatic initialization and
>   update behaviors for the first TIMESTAMP column by explicitly
>   assigning it a constant DEFAULT value

working Query

```
CREATE TABLE mytbl.customer(
CustID int( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
FirstName varchar( 40 ) ,
LastName varchar( 40 ) ,
Street varchar( 50 ) ,
City varchar( 40 ) ,
State varchar( 40 ) ,
ZipCode varchar( 5 ) ,
Telephone varchar( 20 ) ,
CellPhone varchar( 20 ) ,
CellCarrier varchar( 20 ) ,
UserName varchar( 20 ) ,
PASSWORD varchar( 10 ) ,
SecretQuestion varchar( 80 ) ,
SecretAnswer varchar( 50 ) ,
UtilityCompanyID int( 10 ) ,
SwUpgrade int( 10 ) DEFAULT 1,
DateToSignIn timestamp DEFAULT 0 ,
LastLoginTime timestamp DEFAULT 0,
STATUS varchar( 20 ) DEFAULT 'Inacitve',
Email1 varchar( 60 ) ,
Email2 varchar( 60 ) ,
PoolID int( 10 ) ,
DeviceID int( 10 ) ,
Last_Modified_Timestamp timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( CustID )
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1
```

Answer (score 0):

To specify automatic default or updating for a `TIMESTAMP` column other than the first one, you must suppress the automatic initialization and update behaviors for the first TIMESTAMP column by explicitly assigning it a constant DEFAULT value (for example, **DEFAULT 0** or **DEFAULT '2003-01-01 00:00:00'**). Then, for the other TIMESTAMP column, the rules are the same as for the first TIMESTAMP column, except that if you omit both of the DEFAULT and ON UPDATE clauses, no automatic initialization or updating occurs.

[SOURCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html)